# altering a block that is embedded in a view

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a view and in the header of the view, I am rendering a custom block. The block is showing up just fine, however, I need to alter it and I cannot seem to figure this out. I have tried `hook_preprocess_block`, `hook_block_view_alter` and a couple others. I know the ID of my block but it isn't helping.

If I am embedding the block in the view and I want to alter the block, do I need to first alter the view and tell it to rerender the block? I am using drupal 8. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're displaying a block_content entity.

That is not actually rendered through the block system, it's an entity, so you need to implement hook_block_content_view() (see hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view() for documentation)

Comment: Yes and specifically `Global: Rendered entity - Custom block (Global: Rendered entity - Custom block)`. I added `function avanir_block_content_view(...){ kint($build); }` to my theme file and nothing is outputting on the screen. I also figured out the twig name and changing the twig template didn't actually change what was rendered in the view (which I think is what you meant in your answer).

Comment: I meant to say no kint messages are outputting on my screen

Comment: that's because you need a module to implement a hook, not a theme. themes can only implement a few specific alter hooks. And custom blocks have no template on their own, so there's no preprocess either.

Comment: ah, well that is a huge diff between 7 and 8 that I am just figuring out. Thank you

Comment: This really helped and I got it working. Thank you very much.